# jQuery issue with If statement not working correctly

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("[name=q58]").each(function (i) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            var selection = $(this).val();
            alert('Q58 Value = '+selection)
            if (selection == '1') {
                $("#region").show();

                $("[name=q59]").each(function (i) {
                    $(this).click(function () {
                        var selection = $(this).val();
                        alert('Q59 Value = '+selection)
                        if (selection == '1') {
                            $("#location").show();
                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#east, #north, #scotland, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                            $("#central").show();
                        }
                        else if (selection == '2') {
                            $("#location").show();
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #north, #scotland, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                            $("#east").show();
                        }
                        else if (selection == '3') {
                            $("#location").show();
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #east, #scotland, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                            $("#north").show();
                        }
                        else if (selection == '4') {
                            $("#location").show();
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #east, #north, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                            $("#scotland").show();
                        }
                        else if (selection == '5') {
                            $("#location").show();
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #east, #north, #scotland, #southwest").hide();
                            $("#southeast").show();
                        }
                        else if (selection == '6') {
                            $("#location").show();
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #east, #north, #scotland, #southeast").hide();
                            $("#southwest").show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#location").hide();
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #east, #north, #scotland, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                        }             
                    });
                });

            }
            else if (selection == '10') {
                $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("#central, #east, #north, #scotland, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                $("#location").hide();
                $("#region").show();
            }
            else {
                $("input:radio[name^='q59']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("#region").hide();
                $("#location").hide();
                $("#central").hide();
            }             
        });
    });




});
```

Working, or rather not so working, example in JsFiddle: See example in JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ExPUu/1/

The following odd behaviour occurs:

The user selects `Aftersales`, they then see `q59` and can select either `Central` or `East` and then see `q60` and choose a further option.  This works fine.

If the user selects `Bus, Coach and Engines` they don't get any further options - again works fine.

The odd behaviour is when the user selects `Sales` if they select this, they should be able to then select `Central` or `East` - if they have clicked `Sales` and nothing else, this works fine.  **BUT** if they had selected `Aftersales` and then changed their mind and selected `Sales` and then select either `Central` or `East` - it then displays `q60` and it shouldn't.

I've been looking through my jQuery code and cannot see where I am going wrong.  Or is this an oddity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with event binding
In case of `AfterSales`, you are binding click event to q59. So when user selects `Sales` and select something from q59, the click handler executes. This is the piece of code that is causing the problem:

```
$("[name=q59]").each(function (i) {
  $(this).click(function () { ...
```

You can avoid this by either unbinding the event or using some condition inside the event to check whether `AfterSales` is selected or `Sales` is selected.

To unbind use

```
$("[name=q59]").each(function (i) {
                $(this).unbind('click');
                });
```

in else part.

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLa7d/)

Comment: What I don't understand is that code should only be available if the users has select `Aftersales` - if they select anything else, that code shouldn't fire.  Or is it because once it is bound it works regardless?  Not sure how to stop this - any advice?  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Once a click handler is bound with q59, it will execute every time any option is clicked in q50. See my updated answer for solution

Comment: Thanks - hadn't realised that once it was bound it would stay bound - learnt something new - appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code get some logic problem, i fix below try......

> $(document).ready(function(){

```
    $("[name=q58]").each(function (i) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            var selection = $(this).val();
            alert('Q58 Value = '+selection)
            if (selection == '1') {
                $("#region").show();

                $("[name=q59]").each(function (i) {
                    $(this).click(function () {
                        var selection = $(this).val();
                        alert('Q59 Value = '+selection)
                        if (selection == '1') {
                            if($("[name=q58]:checked").val() == 1){
                            $("#location").show();
                            }

                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#east, #north, #scotland, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                            if($("[name=q58]:checked").val() == 1){
                                $("#central").show();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (selection == '2') {

                            if($("[name=q58]:checked").val() == 1){
                            $("#location").show();
                            }
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #north, #scotland, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                            if($("[name=q58]:checked").val() == 1){
                                $("#east").show();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (selection == '3') {
                            $("#location").show();
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #east, #scotland, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                            $("#north").show();
                        }
                        else if (selection == '4') {
                            $("#location").show();
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #east, #north, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                            $("#scotland").show();
                        }
                        else if (selection == '5') {
                            $("#location").show();
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #east, #north, #scotland, #southwest").hide();
                            $("#southeast").show();
                        }
                        else if (selection == '6') {
                            $("#location").show();
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #east, #north, #scotland, #southeast").hide();
                            $("#southwest").show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#location").hide();
                            $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                                   this.checked = false;
                            });
                            $("#central, #east, #north, #scotland, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                        }             
                    });
                });

            }
            else if (selection == '10') {
                $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("#central, #east, #north, #scotland, #southeast, #southwest").hide();
                $("#location").hide();
                $("#region").show();
            }
            else {
                $("input:radio[name^='q59']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='central-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='east-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='north-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='scotland-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='southeast-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("input:radio[name^='southwest-']").each(function(i) {
                       this.checked = false;
                });
                $("#region").hide();
                $("#location").hide();
                $("#central").hide();
            }             
        });
    });




});
```

58.
        
        
            In which Area do you work:      
        
            
                
                        
                         **Aftersales**
                    
                        
                         **Bus, Coach and Engines**
                    
                        
                        
                         **Sales**

```
    <div class="row" style="display:none;" id="region">
    <div class="col1">
        59.
    </div>
    <div class="col2a width400">
        In which Region do you work:        </div>
    <div class="direct2">
        <table style="table2">
            <tr id="trr1" onmouseover="changeBackgroundColor(this.id)" onmouseout="changeBackgroundColor2(this.id)">
                    <td class="td1"><input  name="q59" value="1" id="q591" type="radio"/></td>
                    <td class="td3"><label for="q591"> <b>Central</b></label></td>
                </tr><tr id="trr2" onmouseover="changeBackgroundColor(this.id)" onmouseout="changeBackgroundColor2(this.id)">
                    <td class="td1"><input  name="q59" value="2" id="q592" type="radio"/></td>
                    <td class="td3"><label for="q592"> <b>East</b></label></td>
                </tr>       </table>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="display:none;" id="location">
    <div class="col1">
        60.
    </div>
    <div class="col2a width400">
        In which Location do you work:      </div>
    <div class="direct2" style="display:none;" id="central">
        <table style="table2">
            <tr id="trlc1" onmouseover="changeBackgroundColor(this.id)" onmouseout="changeBackgroundColor2(this.id)">
                    <td class="td1"><input  name="central-q60" value="1" id="q601" type="radio"/></td>
                    <td class="td3"><label for="q601"> <b>Customer Operations</b></label></td>
                </tr><tr id="trlc2" onmouseover="changeBackgroundColor(this.id)" onmouseout="changeBackgroundColor2(this.id)">
                    <td class="td1"><input  name="central-q60" value="2" id="q602" type="radio"/></td>
                    <td class="td3"><label for="q602"> <b>Parts</b></label></td>
                </tr><tr id="trlc3" onmouseover="changeBackgroundColor(this.id)" onmouseout="changeBackgroundColor2(this.id)">
                    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="direct2" style="display:none;" id="east">
        <table style="table2">
            <tr id="trle5" onmouseover="changeBackgroundColor(this.id)" onmouseout="changeBackgroundColor2(this.id)">
                    <td class="td1"><input  name="east-q60" value="5" id="q605" type="radio"/></td>
                    <td class="td3"><label for="q605"> <b>Boston</b></label></td>
                </tr><tr id="trle6" onmouseover="changeBackgroundColor(this.id)" onmouseout="changeBackgroundColor2(this.id)">
                    <td class="td1"><input  name="east-q60" value="6" id="q606" type="radio"/></td>
                    <td class="td3"><label for="q606"> <b>Doncaster VMU</b></label></td>
                </tr><tr id="trle7" onmouseover="changeBackgroundColor(this.id)" onmouseout="changeBackgroundColor2(this.id)">
                                </table>
    </div>
```